# Boto run_instances() - unexpected keyword argument 'tag_specifications'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to start an aws instance in via a python3 script. It works fine, but am now trying to add some tags to the instance with no luck. I am trying the following, but get a "unexpected keyword argument 'tag_specifications'" error.

```
import boto.ec2
conn=boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
conn.run_instances('ami-12345',instance_type='c5.large',key_name='test.prod',
         security_groups=['ProductionInstance'],instance_profile_name='TestProductionProcessor',
         tag_specifications=[{'Key': 'Name','Value': 'TEST'}])
```

I have checked botocore upto date etc.

Thanks

Comment: **Side-note:** You appear to be using an out-of-date version of `boto`. These days, it is recommended that you use [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is successfully executed on Python 3.7;

```
import boto3.ec2

conn=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='eu-west-1')
tags=[
  {'Key':'Name','Value': 'Test'},
]
tag_specification=[{'ResourceType': 'instance','Tags': tags},]
conn.run_instances(ImageId='ami-12345',
                   TagSpecifications=tag_specification,
                   InstanceType='c5.large',
                   SecurityGroupIds=['sg-12345'], #change value of SecurityGroupIds as per your setup
                   IamInstanceProfile={
                     'Name': 'TestProductionProcessor'
                   },
                   MaxCount=1,
                   MinCount=1,
                   SubnetId='subnet-12345' #change value of SubnetId as per your setup
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with

```
TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'instance',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'Test'
                },
            ]
        }
```